# What do resumable termination semantics look like for exception handling?

Tags: c++, error-handling, exception

I read the following statement on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Termination_semantics) in regards to C++ error handling:

> **Termination semantics**
>   Exception handling mechanisms in contemporary languages are typically
>   non-resumable ("termination semantics") as opposed to hardware
>   exceptions, which are typically resumable. This is based on experience
>   of using both, as there are theoretical and design arguments in favor
>   of either decision; these were extensively debated during C++
>   standardization discussions 1989–1991, which resulted in a definitive
>   decision for termination semantics.

What exactly does resumable semantics imply about program state and control flow?
In an alternate universe where C++ had gotten resume-able exceptions, would it mean that this program prints `resumed`?

```
#include <iostream>

void function(){
    throw "";
    std::cout << "resumed" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    try{function();}
    catch(...){}
}
```

Was the intention to rewind the stack, but keep it preserved so that it could be jumped back to after the exception was caught?  Or does the concept of resumable exceptions equate to strategies analogous to `errno` in C?

I'm not sure that I understand the concept because I may not have used a language that does it.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means: the program would print "resumed". On POSIX platforms, signals can be thought of as resumable exceptions: when the signal handler returns, execution continues from where the received signal originally interrupted it.

Comment: Just because you mention it does not make this a C question.

Comment: And that's not even related to or does require a stack. It is much the same in other languages with exception handling, e.g. Python.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Not all signals allow continuation. And once can mess up resumeability for those which allow it.

Comment: I wouldn't say this program would print "resumed". Because the *caller* is catching the exception, that implies the `function()` has already finished executing by the time it's caught. Rather, resumable exceptions would have an exception handler defined elsewhere that can choose to resume execution when an *external* issue is raised (just like a signal handler).